# Clicking an ImageButton to change to a different image everytime

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an `ImageButton`, which as `false` appears as a `gray image`, while as `true` appears as a `green image`. If I use `state_pressed="true"` and `state_pressed="false"` the function DOES work, however I need to hold the `left-click button` for the button to change to `true`.

P.S: I do believe that I am using the wrong `state` but I have tried the others but didn't work.

**My question is**: How do I keep the `image` as `true` with just clicking **once** on the `ImageButton`?

Code:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/green_clock" android:state_selected= "true"> </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/grey_clock" android:state_selected="false"> </item>
</selector>`

Java File:

```
public void onClickClock(View v)
{
    ImageButton clockBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.Clock);
    clockBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.clock);
}
```

activity.xml:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Clock"
    android:src="@drawable/clock"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
    android:onClick="onClickClock" />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add setSelected()

```
public void onClickClock(View v) {
    ImageButton clockBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.Clock);
    clockBtn.setSelected(!clockBtn.isSelected());
}
```

Comment: Works thanks! Can you please explain what that line does exactly? Much appreciated!

Comment: It sets a flag on the view, and this determines which of the 2 images is displayed, according to your XML: grey for not selected, green for selected.